# Bounds on numbers of matchings of given sizes in bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory, bipartite-graphs

I am interested in the following question:

For which sets ${m_1,\ldots m_k}$ of positive integers do there exist bipartite graphs having exactly $m_i$ matchings of size $i$ for each $1\leq i \leq k$, and no matchings larger than $k$?

Ideally I would like to find a complete classification of such sets, or else an algorithm which, given a set of numbers, will (theoretically) construct a bipartite graph with the desired properties if one exists.  However, I realise that this is highly unlikely!  In which case, I would like to know as much as possible about the restrictions on such sets.

For example, assume that our desired graph consists of two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ of vertices with edges between them, such that $|A|\leq |B|$, and such that there are no completely unconnected vertices.  Then $|A|=k$.  As $m_1$ is simply the number of edges of the graph, we must have $m_1\geq k$ and $m_i\leq {m_1 \choose i}$ for all $i$.

This is just off the top of my head; I'm sure there are many more restrictions which can be easily found.  Does anyone know to what extent this problem has been studied?  I'd be grateful for any information or references.

Comment: One strong condition is that if you make a polynomial whose coefficients are these counts, then it has only real zeros.  This was proved long ago by Heilmann and Lieb. Godsil's book on algebraic combinatorics is a place to look for this type of thing. I very much doubt that a complete classification is possible.

Comment: A nice result would be that the sequence m_i is unimodal.  I do not know of a proof or counterexample.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2012.02.15

Comment: @Gerhard: They are unimodal and even log-concave. This consequence and others are cited in this thesis: http://www.math.kth.se/~pbranden/Avhandling.pdf

Comment: @Gerhard: And here is a nice self-contained proof: http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~kratt/artikel/matching.html

Comment: Thank you.  Let's see if my smartphone can handle dvi format.  Gerhard "Or Try A Different Box" Paseman, 2012.02.15